# 2D Ising model to obtain magnetism and energy for 2 dimension spin lattice

Tags: python-2.7

I try to obtain magnetism and energy for 2 dimension spin lattice but the figures are not correct. Here, `L` is the lattice dimension, `mn` is the magnetism, `Trange` is the temperature. For the 2 dimension lattice I want to simulate magnetism and average energy with Ising model. But the figures are not corrected.

```
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
L=10
J=1.0
NStep=10 #montcarlo steps
J=1.0
def defS(L):
    S=np.random.choice([1,-1],(L,L))
    return S
def energy(S,L):
    E=0.0
    for i in range (L):
        for j in range (L):
            E+=-S[i,j]*(S[(i+1)%L,j]+S[(i-1)%L,j]+S[i,(j+1)%L]+S[i,(j-1)%L])
    E=E/2.0
    return E
def metropolis(W,S):
    E=energy(S,L)
    mn=sum(S)
    i=np.random.randint(0,L)
    j=np.random.randint(0,L)
    NN=(S[(i+1)%L,j]+S[(i-1)%L,j]+S[i,(j+1)%L]+S[i,(j-1)%L])
    if W[4+NN] >=np.random.rand():
        S[i,j]=-S[i,j]
    return mn,E
Eav=[]
mav=[]
Trange=np.linspace(0.5,4,20)
for T in Trange:
    W=np.zeros(10*10)
    W[4+4]=np.exp(-8*J/T)
    W[4+2]=np.exp(-4*J/T)
    W[4+0]=np.exp(0.0*J/T)
    W[4-2]=np.exp(4.0*J/T)
    W[4-4]=np.exp(8.0*J/T)
    for i in range(NStep):
        for j in range(9):
            (mn,E)=metropolis(W,defS(L))
    Eav.append(E/NStep)
    mav.append(mn/NStep)
print Eav, mav
plot(Trange, Eav, label='E(T)')
show()
plot(Trange, mav, label='E(T)')
show()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because #1, This is probably more appropriate on physics stack exchange, #2, When you say something is wrong, th have to specify exactly what is wrong.

Comment: i mean the figure (average energy versus time) is not corrected